# How can I save recordings and change appearance in bigbluebutton in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, plugins, bigbluebutton

I use bigbluebutton on a separate server and my website on another. So I used bigbluebutton plugin for wordpress and connected the bigbluebutton and my website together.

I have 2 problems.

1. There is no option to enable saving recordings in bigbluebutton plugin in wordpress. Is there any way that I could achieve this and save a recorded video of each conference to mp4 on a location of my website server?
2. How can I customize the HTML elements of bigbluebutton conference pages ? ( The welcome picture and the buttons and chat menu etc )

I did not use my own API. So I can't really figure out how bigbluebutton plugin works.

I also looked in bigbluebutton docs but could not find much about the html customization and where the related file could be. The bugblue server is ubuntu by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I customize the HTML elements of bigbluebutton conference pages ? ( The welcome picture and the buttons and chat menu etc )

You can do it in Dashboard > Design > Customizer > Additional CSS

Answer (score 0):

the Plugin code is all php, and you can edit the wordpress pages with any editor.

As for the BBB html5 client,  you need to checkout the source of the html5 client on the bbb server, setup the dev enviroment to make UI changes.
https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.3/dev.html#developing-the-html5-client

you can also configure a bunch of stuff like the welcome message/default presentation etc, thru config file changes.   The FAQS document the most common customizations.